# style variable inside the language sources (UWP app C#)

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this value in my source file in C# app, Is there a way to set custom style to the variable without break the string into multi strings

```
<data name="Document_Deleted_Notification_Intro" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>The file {0} has been deleted:</value>
</data>
```

and this is how i display it in the view

```
                            <TextBlock
                                x:Name="NotificationInfo"
                                Margin="{StaticResource XXXSmallTopMargin}"
                                Foreground="{ThemeResource NotificationTextForeground}"
                                TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                <Run Text="{Binding NotificationMsg}" />                    
                            </TextBlock>
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is the behavior you expect? Do you want to put the string in "<data></data>" into "Run Text"?